# How to fix no product found error by wrong index command in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I was trying to update index via ubuntu command line, instead of `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` i have typed `/usr/bin/php7.3 php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

After that none of the products visible in category pages. I have redeployed, reindexed and cleared all cache, but not able to resolve the issue.

my magento verison is 2.4.x

Answer (score 0):

Add all configurable product sku's & configurable variations in csv file and import the file using magento product import section. Make sure you select "add/Update" action, it will fix the problem. If not, re-upload entire product catalog once again.

After import run indexing once again.

Example import data.

[image: sku,config_variation]